# sublimetext slow sync remote -> local

Tags: sftp, sublimetext3

I am using sublimetext3 text editor and linked my local to a remote server.  When the code is changed on the remote and I sync it, it takes a long time to sync.  Is there a way to speed this up?
Thanks

Comment: How are you connected to the remote server? Are you saving locally and then syncing by SFTP, or do you have the server mounted as a network drive?

Comment: I have a local copy of the the remote and use sublime sync remote to local

Comment: HELP IT's SUPER SLOW

Answer (score 4):

The only way to speed synchronization up seems to be the set the `ignore_regexes` options to exclude large folders that won't be edited (e.g. libary folders).

You can exclude folders by setting something like this:

```
"ignore_regexes": [
        /* leave default rules*/
        "/var/www/someFolderLike/Lib/Zend/",
        "/var/www/anotherFolder/",
]
```

*Folder paths might need to be relative to your server root path.*

Comment: even with rules it doesn't speeds up. reason for that is script first check folders which are on server ; later filters them with regex and only after that check local files ( in case of sync remote to local )